# Prove that a random variable is of a certain form

Tags: probability-theory

$(\Omega,F,P)$ is some probability space, X is a random variable on this space. Prove that, if $F=\{\emptyset,A,A^{C},\Omega\}$ for some $A \subset \Omega$, then X is of the form:

$X(\omega)=c_1$ if $\omega \in A$
and
$X(\omega)=c_2$ if $\omega \in A^{C}$
$c_1$, $c_2$ are constants.

---

My approach thus far:
1) going from $\Bbb R$ to $\Omega$
assume $\omega_1 \in A, \omega_2 \in A^{C}, \omega_3 \notin \Omega$, $X(\omega_1)=c_1$, $X(\omega_2)=c_2$
then:
$X^{-1}(\omega_1)=A$
$X^{-1}(\omega_2)=A^{C}$
$X^{-1}(\omega_3)=\emptyset$
Hence, $F=\{\emptyset,A,A^{C},\Omega\}$
Is that even correct?

2) going from $\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$
I can't come up with anything that seems somewhat reasonable...
One idea though: I just did a proof that showed that the random variable of a trivial $\sigma$-algebra is a constant. Hence, one could you argue that the individual events are trivial $\sigma$-algebras themselves and can only have one constant assigned to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable, then by an easy consequence of the definition: $$\{X= \alpha\}\in F$$

for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Take $\omega \in A$ (if $A$ is empty there's nothing to prove) and put $c_1=X(\omega)$. Since $F=\{\emptyset,A,A^c,\Omega\}$ and $\omega \in A$, it follows that:

$$\{X=c_1\}=A \ \text{or} \ \{X=c_1\}=\Omega$$

Can you take it from here?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, $\{X=c_1\}=\{x \in \Omega : X(x)=c_1\}$.

Since $\{X=c_1\}\in F$, there are four possibilities: $$\{X=c_1\}=\emptyset, \{X=c_1\}=A, \{X=c_1\}=A^c \ \text{or} \ \{X=c_1\}=\Omega$$

- The first possibility, $\{X=c_1\}=\emptyset$, is impossible since $\omega \in \{X=c_1\}$.
- If $\{X=c_1\}=A^c$, then $\omega \in A^c$, which is contradictory to our choice of $\omega$.

We are therefore left with $\{X=c_1\}=A$ or $\{X=c_1\}=\Omega$.

If you take $\omega ' \in A^c$ and put $c_2=X(\omega')$, the same reasosing shows that $\{X=c_2\}=A^c$ or $\{X=c_2\}=\Omega$.

Note that it could be that $c_1=c_2$, i.e. $X \equiv c_1$. Your claim is still valid in this (trivial) case.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand the "or" statement. If $\{X=c_1\}=A$ it is automatically in $/Omega$, too. Therefore, should it not be "and"?
Going forward with the proof:  
Since $\omega \in A$, it follows $\omega \notin A^{C}$ and $\{X=c_1\} \ne A^{C}$  
Hence, you need a new c to assign to $A^{C}$?

Comment: @Dahlai I have added an additional explanation. Does it help?

Comment: it does. The next step would be to show that $\{X=c_1\}$ is only in $A$ and for $c_2$ only is part of only $A^{C}$, respectively,  
or is this already proofed by the rationale of $\omega'$ and the complementary of $A$ and $A^{C}$?

Comment: I think the argument I gave above using $\omega '$ would suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your exhaustive answer really helped, also in getting a better grasp on random variables in general!

Comment: You're very welcome!